# how to separate js, html and php files

Tags: php, jquery

I need help.
When I throw the javascript code from the create_table.php file, and add it into script.js file, then does not work delete row in the table.
How to separate this files?, can someone help me make this work? What's wrong?
Thx.

index_table.html

```
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en'>
<head>
<title>Table</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="write_table"></div><br /><br />
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"create_table.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $("#write_table").html(data);
    }});
});
```

create_table.php

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button.delete').click(function(e){
  var parent = $(this).closest('tr');
    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      data: parent,
      success: function(){
      parent.fadeOut('fast', function(){
      parent.remove();
      });
    }
 });                
});
});
</script>
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL + E_NOTICE);
$tabela = new Tabela(); 
$header;
$data= array (      
        array ("row_1", "row_1", "row_1", null),    
        array ("row_2", "row_2", "row_2", "row_2"),
        array ("row_3", "row_3", "row_3", "row_3"),
        array ("row_4", "row_4", "row_4", "row_4")
);
$header = array("col_1","col_2","col_3","col_4"); 
$tablica1 = $tabela->NapraviTabelu($header, $data, true, true, true);
echo $tablica1;
class Tabela {
    function __construct() {
    }
public function NapraviTabelu($header, $data, $add=true, $edit=true, $delete=true){ 
$tablica1 = "<table border='3' id='tablicaId'><thead><tr>";     
  foreach ($header as $head){           
  $tablica1 = $tablica1."<th width='120px'>$head</th>"; 
  }
if($edit || $delete){
  $tablica1 .= "<th height='44px'>/*******/</th>";
 }
$tablica1 .="</tr></thead>";
  if (isset($data)){        
    foreach($data as $row){
    $tablica1 .="<tr>";
    foreach($row as $column){
  if ($column !=''){
    $tablica1 .= "<td height='44px'>$column</td>";  
  }
  else {$tablica1 .="<td></td>";}
  }                                         
if($edit || $delete)                
$tablica1 .= "<td align='right'>";
if($edit){$tablica1 .= "<button title='Edit'  type='submit'><img src='Update.png'/>  </button>";}
if($delete){$tablica1 .= "<button name='cmdEdit' class='delete' title='Delete'   type='submit'><img src='Remove.png'/></button>";}  
$tablica1 .= "</td></tr>";
}
return $tablica1 ."</table>";           
}
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Should work fine, does your console show any errors?

Answer (score 2):

Since `create_table.php` is loaded through `ajax`, the elements within it do not exist at the time the `index_table.html` DOM is ready.  You will either need to execute this code after the ajax call completes, or use event delegation as below.

Instead of `$('button.delete').click(function(e){` do the following:

```
$('#write_table').on('click', 'button.delete', function(e){
   /* ... */
});
```

You can read more about event delegation in the [`on` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).